# Combinatorics with repetition after specific interval

Tags: combinatorics

I have to choose $K$ values $N$ such that the $K$ values that are chosen can be repeated after $10$ other $k$ elements

I feel like you need to consider the order too because you need to keep track of repetition after $10$ elements

I know the formula for $N$ choose $K$ with repetition, how can I plug this $10$ in the formula to achieve the desired result.

```
n + k - 1Ck = (n+k-1)!/(k! (N-1)!)
```

or is it some other formula altogether?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You want to choose $k$ objects out of $[n]$, but you can repeat an element after $10$ others have been chosen? Doesn't that suggest that there's an order to the elements you're picking, hence this is a permutation, not a combination?

Comment: The result need not contain repetition, but if it contains repetition, the elements that get repeated should occur after 10 other _k_ elements.

Comment: If there's order, then this is a permutation. Furthermore, this exercise becomes a lot more difficult because there can be many repetitions. I don't think this can be given in such a simple formula.